# how to pass command line parameters to invoked session in powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, invoke-command

How can i pass command line parameters to a session which is invoked using 'invoke-command' in powershell 2.0

my script:

```
param(
    [string]$hostname = 'my_server_name'
)

function createSession($hostname){
    return New-PSSession -ComputerName $hostname -Credential $env:UserDomain\$env:UserName
}
$session = createSession $hostname
invoke-command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
   write-host $hostname
   write-host $using:hostname
   write-host $script:hostname 
   write-host '**test text**'

}
    Exit-PSSession
```

Output: (I'm getting empty string if i print the parameter value directly.)

```
**test text**
```

Comment: `-ScriptBlock {} -ArgumentList $hostname `

Comment: Alternatively, you can reference variables from the parent session as such: `$using:hostname`. I'm fairly sure that's PSv2 friendly.

Comment: I tried -ArgumentList & $using options. but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use param block

```
$hostname = $env:computername
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { param($hostname)
    Write-OutPut $hostname
} -ArgumentList $hostname
```

Answer (score 1):

```
param(
    [string]$hostname = 'my_server_name'
)

function createSession($hostname){
    return New-PSSession -ComputerName $hostname -Credential $env:UserDomain\$env:UserName
}
$session = createSession $hostname
invoke-command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
$hostname=$using:hostname

or

$hostname=$script:hostname
   write-host $hostname
   write-host '**test text**'

}
    Exit-PSSession
```

Hope any one of the above helps,If Not Please look at the concept of scoping variables in powershell,May be they will help
[Powershell variable scoping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Scopes)